# How to get the current bar width of Flot Chart?

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, flot

I am using Flot Chart for my Bar Chart... and I am using chart value indicator at the top like this...

```
var p1 = $.plot($("#received-against-assigned"), data1, {
  xaxis: {
      ticks : ticks,
      axisLabel: "Accounts",
      axisLabelUseCanvas: true,
      axisLabelFontSizePixels: 12,
      axisLabelFontFamily: "Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, Tahoma, sans-serif",
      axisLabelPadding: 10
  },
  yaxis: {
      axisLabel: "Emails",
      axisLabelUseCanvas: true,
      axisLabelFontSizePixels: 12,
      axisLabelFontFamily: "Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, Tahoma, sans-serif",
      axisLabelPadding: 5
  },
  grid: {
      hoverable: true,
      clickable: false,
      borderWidth: 0
  },
  legend: {
      // labelBoxBorderColor: "none",
      // position: "left"
      show: true,
      noColumns: 5,
      container: "#bar-legend-2"
  },
  series: {
      shadowSize: 1
  },
  tooltip: true
});
```

This is the code for the Indicator...

```
$.each(p1.getData()[0].data, function(i, el){
  var o = p1.pointOffset({x: el[0], y: el[1]});
    $('<div class="data-point-label">' + el[1] + '</div>').css( {
      position: 'absolute',
      left: o.left - 32, // Notice here...
      top: o.top - 20,
      display: 'none'
    }).appendTo(p1.getPlaceholder()).fadeIn('slow');
});
```

Now you can see I am setting the `left: o.left - 32` which is a static way... I am having variable number of bars... Depends upon the number of accounts... So the number 32 is not good enough...

If I can somehow get the current bar width... then I can calculate and align the indicators properly...

Thanks...

Comment: `$("CSS Selector").width()` will give you the width. But this can be used after the dom gets loaded for that particular selector.

Comment: The entire thing is in a canvas... I have tried inspect element... but there no Element I can find for the Bars... It has to come out of the plugin itself I think...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You get the bar width (in axis units) from

```
var barWidthInUnits = p1.getOptions().series.bars.barWidth;
```

If you want to calculate the width in pixels you also need to get the scale factor of the x axis

```
var barWidthInPixels = barWidthInUnits * p1.getXAxes()[0].scale;
```

Half of this should be the offset you need for your value indicators.